# How can I prevent my function from running on every click?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a dynamic drop down list using HTML and JavaScript, but every time I click on the drop down I get a new set of duplicate values. How can I prevent this from happening? I would prefer to stick to vanilla JS and html

```js
function yearsArray(num) {
    let years=document.getElementById("years")
    let year=[...Array(num+1).keys()]
    year.shift()
    year.shift()
    year.forEach(element => {
        switch (element) {
            case 1:
                years.add(new Option(element,element,true))
                break;
            default:
                years.add(new Option(element,element,false))
                break;
        }
    })
}
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1{
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <title>Simple Interest Calculator</title>
    <body>
        <div class="maindiv">
            <h1>Simple Interest Calculator</h1>
            <form>
                <label for="principal">Amount</label> 
                <input type="number" name="principal" id="principal">  <br/>
                <label for="rate">Interest Rate</label>
                <input type="range" id="rate" name="rate" min="0" max="20" step=".25">
                <span id="rate_val">10.25%</span>  <br/>
                <label for="years">No. of Years </label>
                <select id="years" name="years" onclick="yearsArray(20)">
                    <option selected value="1">1</option>
                </select><br/>
                <!-- Interest : <span id="result"></span><br/> -->
                <button type="submit">Compute Interest</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you need to initialize the drop down every time the user clicks on it?  Can you not just do it once? at page load?

Comment: @blurfus I tried to use the onload event in the select tag but none of the options show up. That's why I used onclick.

Comment: don't use the onload on the select tag, use it on the body?

Comment: it worked thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just run that function once on page load:

(You could of course just create the options using markup)

```js
function yearsArray(num) {
  let years = document.getElementById("years")
  let year = [...Array(num + 1).keys()]
  year.shift()
  year.shift()
  year.forEach(element => {
    switch (element) {
      case 1:
        years.add(new Option(element, element, true))
        break;
      default:
        years.add(new Option(element, element, false))
        break;
    }
  })
}

yearsArray(20);  //<---------- This runs the function on page load
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<title>Simple Interest Calculator</title>

<body>
  <div class="maindiv">
    <h1>Simple Interest Calculator</h1>
    <form>
      <label for="principal">Amount</label>
      <input type="number" name="principal" id="principal"> <br/>
      <label for="rate">Interest Rate</label>
      <input type="range" id="rate" name="rate" min="0" max="20" step=".25">
      <span id="rate_val">10.25%</span> <br/>
      <label for="years">No. of Years </label>
      <select id="years" name="years">
        <option selected value="1">1</option>
      </select><br/>
      <!-- Interest : <span id="result"></span><br/> -->
      <button type="submit">Compute Interest</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I use the onload event on the html select tag

Comment: @user15697542 - Look for this `//<---------- This runs the function on page load` in the javascript section of the snippet in my answer. Just add the line `yearsArray(20);` after your function. Then remove this completely `onclick="yearsArray(20)"`. The code in my answer can be a direct replacement for the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. added the javascript function to the body tag

```
<body onload=yearsArray(20)></body>
```